# invalid syntax in view.py in django.?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I m facing error in Django :invalid syntax (views.py).

```
def deals(request):
    form = deals()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = deals(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        return render_to_response("deals.html", {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
    form = deals()
    return render_to_response("deals.html", {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually an issue with indentation, which manifests as a syntax error. The four lines beginning `if form.is_valid()` should be indented one level.

However, this would still not be the recommended pattern. You don't need the inner `else` at all, and you must redirect after a successful post.

```
def deals(request):
    form = DealsForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DealsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')   # or wherever
    else:
        form = DealsForm()
    return render(request "deals.html", {'form':form})
```

Also I've used the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`, as that uses a RequestContext automatically.

Note that all this is explicitly given in the docs; there's no reason to do anything else.

Comment: when I put this code next error.  deals() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given).

Comment: When you put the code *where*? It's a view, it's always called with the request.

Comment: view.py    def deals(request):
        form = deals()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = deals(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return redirect('/deals/')
        else:
            form = deals()
            return render_to_response("deals.html", {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: You need to call the form something different from the name of the view. I've updated it above to be DealsForm.

Comment: tried to getting error one by one..sorry to ask new error now global name 'DealsForm' is not defined

Comment: Argh, it was an example. You need to **rename** your form class.